# Unregister actions of Broadcast Receiver individually

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to unregister BroadcastReceiver actions individually?

I have two actions for time and date.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_CHANGED" />
```

I want to toggle between them based on user input.

```
mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

unregister(mReceiver) unregisters both the actions.

Is it wise to create multiple receiver objects and register with different filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to create multiple receiver objects and register them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no way to unregister for specific actions